# How to do inline editing in pageblock table values

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, visualforce-component, custom-metadata

I am passing a list to the pageblock table and my table looks like below
[image]

i want to edit the table values. I tried the below code.
This is my VF Page code

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="section2" columns="2" collapsible="true" title="Configure Complexity">
    <apex:pageBlockTable style="margin-left: 80%;width:30%" value="{!LMComplexity}" var="com">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="update, cancelButton"
                                hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                                changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"></apex:inlineEditSupport>
        <apex:column headerValue="Class" value="{!com.Class__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Maximum Days" value="{!com.Maximum_Complexity_Score__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Minimum Days" value="{!com.Minimum_Complexity_Score__c}"/>
        
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:commandButton id="update" action="{!quickUpdat}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

and my controller code looks like this

```
public class profileList {
    public profileList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}
    public List <LM_Default_Weightage__mdt> result{get;set;}
    Boolean testval = false;
            
    public profileList() {
        result= Database.query('Select Class__c, Maximum_Complexity_Score__c,Minimum_Complexity_Score__c From LM_Default_Complexity__mdt');
    }
    public PageReference quickUpdat() {
        try {
            return ApexPages.CurrentPage();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('@@@Error');
            return null;
        }
    }
    public list<LM_Default_Complexity__mdt> getLMComplexity() {
        List<LM_Default_Complexity__mdt> comp=  [Select Class__c, Maximum_Complexity_Score__c,Minimum_Complexity_Score__c From LM_Default_Complexity__mdt];
        return comp;
    }
}
```

So basically i am querying my custom metadata put it in a list and returned it.Finally displaying the returned list in pageblock table. Is the table editable?

Note: I tried directly passing the custom metadata and i cannot edit the table.Custom metadata isn't editable

Comment: Using wrapper class and add checkbox for all rows you can edit it inline.

Comment: Can you please provide me some samples? It would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use an apex:inputField inside the column.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Maximum Days">
 <apex:inputField value="{!com.Maximum_Complexity_Score__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Minimum Days">
 <apex:inputField value="{!com.Minimum_Complexity_Score__c}"/>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: It didn't work either.I am passing a list to this pageblock table

Comment: @SKH Yes, that should work. What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: When i double click on the table row it is not in edit mode. I cannot edit any vaues in the table

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided in your post, can you confirm if you are planning for inline edit on Custom Metadata Type records or Custom object record?

Here is an example code from Salesforce developer guide that shows inline editing. Can you try like below?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_inline_editing.htm

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="records" id="thePage"> 
    <apex:form id="theForm"> 
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock"> 
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="record" id="thePageBlockTable"> 
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!record.Name}" id="AccountNameDOM" /> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!record.Type}" id="AccountTypeDOM" /> 
                    <apex:facet name="header">Type</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!record.Industry}" 
                        id="AccountIndustryDOM" />  
                        <apex:facet name="header">Industry</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" 
                        showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
                <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!save}" id="editButton" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveButton" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="cancelButton" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```